# How to kill a process with 'kill' combined with 'grep'

Tags: bash, process, grep, kill, ps

I'd like to kill a process/script with a simple command using. At the moment I do the following

```
ps -ef | grep myscriptname
kill 123456
```

But is there a way to maybe combine the 2 command together so I don't need to look and manually write the pid, something like this `kill grep myscriptname`?

Comment: Do you know `killall` man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want `pkill`:

```
pkill myscriptname
```

On some systems there is a similar tool called `killall`, but be careful because on Solaris it really does kill everything!

Note that there is also `pgrep` which you can use to replace your `ps | grep` pipeline:

```
pgrep myscriptname
```

It prints the PID for you, and nothing else.

Comment: and so you can use also if pkill is not an option kill $(pgrep myscriptname)

Comment: @VirgileD: Any machine that has pgrep will have pkill.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is using the `pidof` command:

```
kill $(pidof processname)
```

Comment: shall not work if added, say, as an alias in basch.rc. inner command will be executed only once on import

Answer (score 2):

I use `kill $(pgrep <program name>)`, it works.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this simple trick
`pkill -f "my_sript_filename"`

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative, `pgrep` with `xargs`

ps aux | pgrep gitlab | xargs kill

Answer (score -2):

An alternative is piping to the `xargs` command:

`ps -ef | grep myscriptname | xargs kill`

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html

Comment: that causes too much killing. i think you meant: `pgrep myscriptname | xargs kill`